# Moodle all the pages continuously loading after updating to https

Tags: magento, moodle

I have magento and moodle website and both are integrated with magento moodle extension. Recently we have moved all our files to new hosting but website is working good.

Now we have update the website to https and magento website is working fine but moodle website keeps on loading. I am not sure what is the issue. I have checked with my error log too but there is no issue.

[This](https://visionavion.com/) is my moodle website

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

If you update Moodle website to https you need to:

1. Update any hard links that have http in them.
2. Update the config.php wwwroot to include https
3. Purge Caches either through the frond end (search for Purge under the main admin settings) or using CLI.

When I took a look at your site I couldn't see anything wrong with it? Perhaps you could elaborate on what issues are being caused by the change to https? Also provide login credentials if the issue is past the log in page.